# Latex or oil paint for interior stairs

Tags: paint, stairs

Which would be better on interior stairs (they are bare wood right now). Oil or Latex based paint? I should also point out that there are nail heads showing that I can't sink because they are not finish nails. I had another post where I asked about what primer to use, but in this one, I am asking about the eventual topcoat and that will dictate the primer to use.

Used oil based porch and floor paint over oil based primer. Turned out good:
[image]

Comment: I would almost get a exterior or deck or floor paint

Comment: Oil would be better than latex as I feel traffic over latex paint would just peel it off easily. Certainly doesn't stop kids from peeling it off the walls.....  The primer you use should match what finish you're using. Oil-based primer for oil paints and water-based  primer for latex paints.

Comment: I will comment that oil-based primer can be used under latex paints, and in some cases would be preferred. What part(s) of the stairs are we talking about here: treads, risers, bannisters?

Comment: Treads, I decided to use an oil based primer and paint on the treads. The riser have the same oil based primer and will have latex paint (2 different colors)

Comment: I have painted professionally for 30 years. Stairs are my least favorite thing to paint. These look a lot like my own but my treads are oak and stained dark with poly.   How many hours did this take? Looks nice!

Comment: Many hours since they were carpeted before which had to be torn off. Plus a bunch a prep since there weren't painted or varnished before.I wouldn't be surprised if it took around 20 hours. I would have preferred poly threads from the beginning, but since they weren't built with that in mind,had to go with paint to cover up the patching.   Thank you for the complement.